# Notepad++ Regex Extract information

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to extract the numbers which are followed after "segment1", "segment2", etc... For example pattern NS1:segment1>307000. I would like just to have just the 307000. I cannot figure out an easy way to use regex in Notepad++ as I am still learning. Below is a sample of what I would like:

```
/NS1:salesCredits
    NS1:distributions
    NS1:interfaceLineContext>TS</NS1:interfaceLineContext
    NS1:interfaceLineAttributes
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute1>11111</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute1
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute2>TSO</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute2
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute3>TSO1234</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute3
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute4>12345678</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute4
    /NS1:interfaceLineAttributes
    NS1:attribute1/
    NS1:accountClass>REV</NS1:accountClass
    NS1:amount>0.00</NS1:amount
    NS1:orgId>103</NS1:orgId
    NS1:percent>0</NS1:percent
    NS1:segments
    NS1:segment1>307000</NS1:segment1
    NS1:segment2>460075</NS1:segment2
    NS1:segment3>0000</NS1:segment3
    NS1:segment4>321000</NS1:segment4
    NS1:segment5>32181</NS1:segment5
    NS1:segment6>000000</NS1:segment6
    NS1:segment7>00000</NS1:segment7
    /NS1:segments
    /NS1:distributions
    NS1:distributions
    NS1:interfaceLineContext>TS</NS1:interfaceLineContext
    NS1:interfaceLineAttributes
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute1>104009</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute1
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute2>TS</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute2
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute3>TS45678</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute3
    NS1:interfaceLineAttribute4>9875412</NS1:interfaceLineAttribute4
    /NS1:interfaceLineAttributes
    NS1:attribute1/
```

Any help would be appreciated in order to extract that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ to replace, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace menu.

Find: `\s+NS1:segment\d+>(\d+).*|.*`

Replace: `$1`

If `$1` doesn't work try with `\1`.

First it will check for `NS1:segment\d+>(\d+).*`

The match between the parenthesis, called [Capture groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups) will be assigned to $1 since it is the first match.

If it is not a match it will check for `.*` that matches anything thus replacing all the other lines with nothing.

Using the sample you provided it will leave you with:

```
307000
460075
0000
321000
32181
000000
00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too,  is a little modified

Find:  `t\d+>(\d+)|.*?` 
Replace:  `$1`